# Automounting sshfs-share via fstab

Tags: fstab, automount, sshfs

I am automounting a share for a user in `fstab` like so:

`user@192.168.1.123:/home/user/ /home/user/Server/ fuse  auto,user,_netdev,reconnect,uid=1000,gid=1000,IdentityFile=/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa,idmap=user,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=user_uid,gid=user_gid 0 0`

Everything so far works well except for one thing: All files are shown with the correct uid and gid except the ones for the logged in user. The files of the logged in user are shown with owner `root`.

The uids and gids on the local and remote system are identical. I have tested with the options `idmap=file`, `uidfile=...`, `gidfile=...` as well but to no avail.

**Q** What do I miss to get the correct uid for the current user on the local system?